# Write P7M file Cades compliant

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I'm working with my smartcard and x509 cert through Net.Pkcs11.dll component.

I'm able to sign a file, but I don't know how can I create a P7M structure.

I've already seen many examples (BouncyCastle and so on) but all of theme use digital certificate with private key, while my private key is protected by smartcard.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have to use the Net.Pkcs11 component for creating the P7M file? is your smart card [CAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI) compatible? i.e., can you use it normally inside your windows OS?

Comment: Net.Pkcs11 allow me to access to private key of my cert which is placed and protected by my smartcard. Net.Pkcs11 also contain a method Sign(..), but I need to achieve a P7M structure.

Comment: The reason I am asking you if your smart card is CAPI compatible is that if it is (which I guess it probably is), then you can use the [SignedCms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class from the .NET framework to create the P7M file/structure easily. If it is not and you need to do it through the Sign method of Net.Pkcs11, then the way to to this needs more work

Comment: Yes, it is, but my cert is not installed on pc, so no .NET is unable to get private key and sign the message,

Comment: Did you test that? If you open certmgr.msc -> Personal ->Certificates, do you find the certificate there? Even if the cert and key are on the smart card, you should find them there. Finding them there does not mean that your key is on your hard drive.

Comment: Sure. I've tested it. My purpose is access to smartcard without force the user to install the certificate on pc.

Comment: In order to create a Signed CMS object (P7M), you need to have the X509 Certificate of the entity that will sign the data. You need it because you have to embed it into the CMS object. Can you obtain such certificate from the smart card via the Net.Pkcs11 library?

Comment: I'm able to sign my data through smartcard API and certificate placed on smartcard. Now, all what I need is take my arraybyte already signed and push it into p7m structure.

Comment: Just to make sure that we are on the same page, when you say P7M, you mean [CMS/PKCS#7](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3852), right? If this is the case, then the P7M structure needs to include the certificate it self (like the contents of the .CER file) embedded into it. That is why I asked you if you can obtain the public key certificate as a blob from the smart card.

Comment: You are right...and I able to get the public key from my smartcard. My problem is how to create P7M format (which .net object I have to use, etc).